# Python - Making linked lists of same values in matrix

Tags: python, algorithm

Given some matrix, I want to create a linked list of all the 1s in a row and then check if for any of the pointers in any of the rows, if they leave at some column `i`, they point to the same new column. For instance, consider this image:

[image]

All the pointers leaving column C3 point to the same place, themselves. All the pointers leaving column C1 point to the same place, column C2, etc. But the pointers leaving C5 do NOT point to the same column.

I am able to create a linked list by just iterating through each row and then saving the indices of the 1s. However, I am not sure how to create an efficient way of checking whether the arrows that leave a particular column all point to the same place. I could just iterate through all the combinations, but this would be terrible inefficient. How would I proceed?

For testing purposes, here is the matrix from the picture:

`matrix = [[1,1,0,0,0][0,0,1,0,0][1,1,0,1,0][0,0,1,0,1][0,0,1,1,0]]`

Input: The matrix
Output: "False, this matrix doesn't satisfy requirements"
Explanation for output: C5 points to C1 and C3. A matrix only satisfies requirements if all the 1s in a column point to the EXACT same column to the left. So for instance, if (E,C1) = 1, and (E,C3) = 0, then this matrix would satisfy requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make list of sets, list index corresponds to the column, set contains indexes of addressed columns.

When scanning row, add linked column index to set. At the end check set lengths.

Example for your case (I used column names instead of indexes to avoid mistakes):

```
sets[C1] = {C2}
sets[C5] = {C1,C3}
```

Quick-made code:

```
matrix = [[1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[1,1,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,1,0]]
sets = []
for col in range(len(matrix[0])):
    sets.append(set())
for row in range(len(matrix)):
    leftone = -1
    for col in range(len(matrix[row])):
        if matrix[row][col] == 1:
            if leftone < 0:
                sets[col].add(col)
            else:
                sets[col].add(leftone)
            leftone = col

for col in range(len(matrix[0])):
     print(sets[col], len(sets[col]) == 1)

>>>
{0} True
{0} True
{2} True
{1, 2} False
{2} True
```

Comment: Can you expand on this? I'm a little lost in translation